# css tables out of alignment with bootstrap

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap-3, bootstrap-4

I've sliced up a bunch of images in Photoshop and exported the slices with the css table mark-up. The css works fine, placing each slice in the correct position, that is, until the bootstrap css file is added to the page. This causes some of the images go out of alignment on a desktop browser but not on a mobile device.

Here's an example of a table that looks fine, until bootstrap.css is placed in the head of the document. In this instance, it's just 1 image, image #3 that's out of alignment (4 pixels down with bootstrap 3, and 6 pixels down with bootstrap 4).

Without Bootstrap

```css
div.Table_01 {
 position:absolute;
 left:0px;
 top:0px;
 width:272px;
 height:340px;
}

div.jyd-01 {
 position:absolute;
 left:0px;
 top:0px;
 width:272px;
 height:68px;
}

div.jyd-02 {
 position:absolute;
 left:0px;
 top:68px;
 width:67px;
 height:71px;
}

div.jyd-03 {
 position:absolute;
 left:67px;
 top:68px;
 width:57px;
 height:15px;
}

div.jyd-04 {
 position:absolute;
 left:124px;
 top:68px;
 width:148px;
 height:71px;
}

div.jyd-05 {
 position:absolute;
 left:67px;
 top:83px;
 width:57px;
 height:56px;
}

div.jyd-06 {
 position:absolute;
 left:0px;
 top:139px;
 width:42px;
 height:201px;
}

div.jyd-07 {
 position:absolute;
 left:42px;
 top:139px;
 width:28px;
 height:24px;
}

div.jyd-08 {
 position:absolute;
 left:70px;
 top:139px;
 width:51px;
 height:201px;
}

div.jyd-09 {
 position:absolute;
 left:121px;
 top:139px;
 width:27px;
 height:23px;
}

div.jyd-10 {
 position:absolute;
 left:148px;
 top:139px;
 width:124px;
 height:115px;
}

div.jyd-11 {
 position:absolute;
 left:121px;
 top:162px;
 width:27px;
 height:178px;
}

div.jyd-12 {
 position:absolute;
 left:42px;
 top:163px;
 width:28px;
 height:177px;
}

div.jyd-13 {
 position:absolute;
 left:148px;
 top:254px;
 width:24px;
 height:86px;
}

div.jyd-14 {
 position:absolute;
 left:172px;
 top:254px;
 width:100px;
 height:86px;
}

body {
  background: yellow;
}
```

```html
<div class="Table_01">
 <div class="jyd-01">
  <img src="https://picsum.photos/272/68?image=990" width="272" height="68" alt="">
 </div>
 <div class="jyd-02">
  <img src="https://picsum.photos/67/71?image=990" width="67" height="71" alt="">
 </div>
 <div class="jyd-03">
  <img src="https://picsum.photos/15/57?image=990" width="57" height="15" alt="">
 </div>
 <div class="jyd-04">
  <img src="https://picsum.photos/148/71?image=990" width="148" height="71" alt="">
 </div>
 <div class="jyd-05">
  <img src="https://picsum.photos/57/56?image=990" width="57" height="56" alt="">
 </div>
 <div class="jyd-06">
  <img src="https://picsum.photos/42/201?image=990" width="42" height="201" alt="">
 </div>
 <div class="jyd-07">
  <img src="https://picsum.photos/28/28?image=990" width="28" height="24" alt="">
 </div>
 <div class="jyd-08">
  <img src="https://picsum.photos/51/201?image=990" width="51" height="201" alt="">
 </div>
 <div class="jyd-09">
  <img src="https://picsum.photos/27/23?image=990" width="27" height="23" alt="">
 </div>
 <div class="jyd-10">
  <img src="https://picsum.photos/124/115?image=990" width="124" height="115" alt="">
 </div>
 <div class="jyd-11">
  <img src="https://picsum.photos/27/178?image=990" width="27" height="178" alt="">
 </div>
 <div class="jyd-12">
  <img src="https://picsum.photos/28/177?image=990" width="28" height="177" alt="">
 </div>
 <div class="jyd-13">
  <img src="https://picsum.photos/24/86?image=990" width="24" height="86" alt="">
 </div>
 <div class="jyd-14">
  <img src="https://picsum.photos/100/86?image=990" width="100" height="86" alt="">
 </div>
</div>
```

With Bottstrap

```css
div.Table_01 {
 position:absolute;
 left:0px;
 top:0px;
 width:272px;
 height:340px;
}

div.jyd-01 {
 position:absolute;
 left:0px;
 top:0px;
 width:272px;
 height:68px;
}

div.jyd-02 {
 position:absolute;
 left:0px;
 top:68px;
 width:67px;
 height:71px;
}

div.jyd-03 {
 position:absolute;
 left:67px;
 top:68px;
 width:57px;
 height:15px;
}

div.jyd-04 {
 position:absolute;
 left:124px;
 top:68px;
 width:148px;
 height:71px;
}

div.jyd-05 {
 position:absolute;
 left:67px;
 top:83px;
 width:57px;
 height:56px;
}

div.jyd-06 {
 position:absolute;
 left:0px;
 top:139px;
 width:42px;
 height:201px;
}

div.jyd-07 {
 position:absolute;
 left:42px;
 top:139px;
 width:28px;
 height:24px;
}

div.jyd-08 {
 position:absolute;
 left:70px;
 top:139px;
 width:51px;
 height:201px;
}

div.jyd-09 {
 position:absolute;
 left:121px;
 top:139px;
 width:27px;
 height:23px;
}

div.jyd-10 {
 position:absolute;
 left:148px;
 top:139px;
 width:124px;
 height:115px;
}

div.jyd-11 {
 position:absolute;
 left:121px;
 top:162px;
 width:27px;
 height:178px;
}

div.jyd-12 {
 position:absolute;
 left:42px;
 top:163px;
 width:28px;
 height:177px;
}

div.jyd-13 {
 position:absolute;
 left:148px;
 top:254px;
 width:24px;
 height:86px;
}

div.jyd-14 {
 position:absolute;
 left:172px;
 top:254px;
 width:100px;
 height:86px;
}

body {
  background: yellow;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="Table_01">
 <div class="jyd-01">
  <img src="https://picsum.photos/272/68?image=990" width="272" height="68" alt="">
 </div>
 <div class="jyd-02">
  <img src="https://picsum.photos/67/71?image=990" width="67" height="71" alt="">
 </div>
 <div class="jyd-03">
  <img src="https://picsum.photos/15/57?image=990" width="57" height="15" alt="">
 </div>
 <div class="jyd-04">
  <img src="https://picsum.photos/148/71?image=990" width="148" height="71" alt="">
 </div>
 <div class="jyd-05">
  <img src="https://picsum.photos/57/56?image=990" width="57" height="56" alt="">
 </div>
 <div class="jyd-06">
  <img src="https://picsum.photos/42/201?image=990" width="42" height="201" alt="">
 </div>
 <div class="jyd-07">
  <img src="https://picsum.photos/28/28?image=990" width="28" height="24" alt="">
 </div>
 <div class="jyd-08">
  <img src="https://picsum.photos/51/201?image=990" width="51" height="201" alt="">
 </div>
 <div class="jyd-09">
  <img src="https://picsum.photos/27/23?image=990" width="27" height="23" alt="">
 </div>
 <div class="jyd-10">
  <img src="https://picsum.photos/124/115?image=990" width="124" height="115" alt="">
 </div>
 <div class="jyd-11">
  <img src="https://picsum.photos/27/178?image=990" width="27" height="178" alt="">
 </div>
 <div class="jyd-12">
  <img src="https://picsum.photos/28/177?image=990" width="28" height="177" alt="">
 </div>
 <div class="jyd-13">
  <img src="https://picsum.photos/24/86?image=990" width="24" height="86" alt="">
 </div>
 <div class="jyd-14">
  <img src="https://picsum.photos/100/86?image=990" width="100" height="86" alt="">
 </div>
</div>
```

I can fix the inexplicable misalignment by changing the css to top:64px except that it will then be misaligned on a mobile device.

A similar thing happens on every single table I've exported. I can't seem to find anything on the issue. I guess I must be the only person still using Photoshop sliced tables and trying to do so with Bootstrap. But I have my reasons. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please create a proper [mcve] that fully shows the issue.

Comment: I'm not quite sure how to go about this. Do you want me to link the image sources to ones hosted on a server?

Comment: Maybe you can recreate the issue using appropriately sized images from a service like https://placeholder.com/ But I think we need to see this somehow, because it isn’t really explicable that you would see whatever is causing this affecting only one specific image, with just the code snippets given.

Comment: BS applies `vertical-align: middle;` to images by default, maybe that causes the issue - default value would be `baseline`, try and apply that to the images and see if it changes things.

Comment: Actually, I don't think the server will allow the linking. As the nature of the problem relates to specific image slices rather than generic images, I can't think of what to do except provide a link to the site where it's a problem. That being said, I have provided ALL the code in the question. I've stripped it down to just this code, and when I add the bootstrap css file, the problem occurs.

Comment: I just read your suggested fix, I'll give it a go...

Comment: Nope, didn't change anything. Totally baffling.

Comment: Without any actual images, this isn’t even testable, at least in Chrome they all collapse down to 0 by 0 pixels, when I just copy&paste your code into a jsfiddle.

Comment: What are the rules here, am I allowed to provide a link to a functional example?

Comment: Well the actual “policy“ on that would be https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254428/ … but if you drop a link here in comments for a quick look, that could help nevertheless.

Comment: @I've added placeholder images and presented a working example without Bootstrap and a not working example with Bootstrap

Comment: @yunzen, thanks heaps for that. So, now we can see the issue. Incidentally, when I was preparing a page to potentially upload on my hosting server, I noticed that removing the !DOCTYPE html tag from the start of the html document fixed the issue. Now I'm completely confused!

Comment: Also, you'll see that it's 3 images out of alignment with bootstrap 4. It's only 1 with bootstrap 3 (and by a different offset).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Bootstrap changes the `line-height` and `font-size` of the `body` element, which is inherited. This is problematic on the small images, as one line—which the image is part of—will be higher than the image.

Setting the `line-height` to zero on the image container `div`s solves your issue

```css
div.Table_01,
div.Table_02,
div.Table_03,
div.Table_04,
div.Table_05,
div.Table_06,
div.Table_07,
div.Table_08,
div.Table_09,
div.Table_10,
div.Table_11,
div.Table_12,
div.Table_13,
div.Table_14 {
  line-height: 0;
}

div.Table_01 {
 position:absolute;
 left:0px;
 top:0px;
 width:272px;
 height:340px;
}

div.jyd-01 {
 position:absolute;
 left:0px;
 top:0px;
 width:272px;
 height:68px;
}

div.jyd-02 {
 position:absolute;
 left:0px;
 top:68px;
 width:67px;
 height:71px;
}

div.jyd-03 {
 position:absolute;
 left:67px;
 top:68px;
 width:57px;
 height:15px;
}

div.jyd-04 {
 position:absolute;
 left:124px;
 top:68px;
 width:148px;
 height:71px;
}

div.jyd-05 {
 position:absolute;
 left:67px;
 top:83px;
 width:57px;
 height:56px;
}

div.jyd-06 {
 position:absolute;
 left:0px;
 top:139px;
 width:42px;
 height:201px;
}

div.jyd-07 {
 position:absolute;
 left:42px;
 top:139px;
 width:28px;
 height:24px;
}

div.jyd-08 {
 position:absolute;
 left:70px;
 top:139px;
 width:51px;
 height:201px;
}

div.jyd-09 {
 position:absolute;
 left:121px;
 top:139px;
 width:27px;
 height:23px;
}

div.jyd-10 {
 position:absolute;
 left:148px;
 top:139px;
 width:124px;
 height:115px;
}

div.jyd-11 {
 position:absolute;
 left:121px;
 top:162px;
 width:27px;
 height:178px;
}

div.jyd-12 {
 position:absolute;
 left:42px;
 top:163px;
 width:28px;
 height:177px;
}

div.jyd-13 {
 position:absolute;
 left:148px;
 top:254px;
 width:24px;
 height:86px;
}

div.jyd-14 {
 position:absolute;
 left:172px;
 top:254px;
 width:100px;
 height:86px;
}

body {
  background: yellow;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="Table_01">
 <div class="jyd-01">
  <img src="https://picsum.photos/272/68?image=990" width="272" height="68" alt="">
 </div>
 <div class="jyd-02">
  <img src="https://picsum.photos/67/71?image=990" width="67" height="71" alt="">
 </div>
 <div class="jyd-03">
  <img src="https://picsum.photos/15/57?image=990" width="57" height="15" alt="">
 </div>
 <div class="jyd-04">
  <img src="https://picsum.photos/148/71?image=990" width="148" height="71" alt="">
 </div>
 <div class="jyd-05">
  <img src="https://picsum.photos/57/56?image=990" width="57" height="56" alt="">
 </div>
 <div class="jyd-06">
  <img src="https://picsum.photos/42/201?image=990" width="42" height="201" alt="">
 </div>
 <div class="jyd-07">
  <img src="https://picsum.photos/28/28?image=990" width="28" height="24" alt="">
 </div>
 <div class="jyd-08">
  <img src="https://picsum.photos/51/201?image=990" width="51" height="201" alt="">
 </div>
 <div class="jyd-09">
  <img src="https://picsum.photos/27/23?image=990" width="27" height="23" alt="">
 </div>
 <div class="jyd-10">
  <img src="https://picsum.photos/124/115?image=990" width="124" height="115" alt="">
 </div>
 <div class="jyd-11">
  <img src="https://picsum.photos/27/178?image=990" width="27" height="178" alt="">
 </div>
 <div class="jyd-12">
  <img src="https://picsum.photos/28/177?image=990" width="28" height="177" alt="">
 </div>
 <div class="jyd-13">
  <img src="https://picsum.photos/24/86?image=990" width="24" height="86" alt="">
 </div>
 <div class="jyd-14">
  <img src="https://picsum.photos/100/86?image=990" width="100" height="86" alt="">
 </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Absolutely brilliant yunzen. This solution worked, and solved something that's had me pulling my hair out for quite some time. Thank you.